# How can a computer create "if" statements using only ones and zeros

Tags: compiler-construction, binary

I understand that programming languages translate certain keywords in computer-readable code, but how can a computer understand it is executing an "if" or a "while" statement when it can only handle ones and zeros? And how did the early programmer's know what to type, using only binary?

Comment: I suggest you to read some book on computer architecture.

Comment: @ShivamKalra Ok, good idea, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @AntonD I think "Structured Computer Organization" by Tanenbaum is a common first text. I haven't read it though.

Comment: @AntonD Search `nptel computer architecture lecture videos` on Google.

Comment: Petzold's "[Code](http://www.charlespetzold.com/code/)" is a nice poetic introduction to the lowest level of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can a computer understand it is executing an "if" or a "while" statement?

The short answer is that the computer does not understand if or while.

The computer executes one simple instruction after another. Each instruction is located at a particular address. There are special "branch" (or "jump") instructions to jump forwards and backwards in the instruction list. Some of these jump instructions are conditional on the value of certain bits in the CPU. For example there is usually a bit that indicates whether the previous calculation was zero. There are also instructions to set these bits, and special jump instructions that only jump *conditionally* based on the value of these bits.

Consider this code:

```
if( a == 0 ){
    b = 1;
}else{
    b = 2;
}
```

This might get compiled to machine code something like the following made-up assembly code (and I'm simplifying this to explain how an if statement might be compiled):

```
;;(address instruction params ;; comments)
   10      TEST        a      ;; set the "ZERO" bit based on whether a is zero
   20      JNZ         50     ;; if ZERO bit is *not* set, jump to 50, otherwise fall through to 30
   30      STORE       b, 1   ;; store 1 in b
   40      JUMP        60     ;; jump over else branch
   50      STORE       b, 2   ;; store 2 in b
   60
```

So the machine knows how to test values and set bits in the [status register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register) (that's where the zero bit is stored). And it knows how to conditionally jump forwards and backwards in the instruction stream (you can probably guess how a while loop is implemented: you make a test and jump *backwards* in the instruction list to make a loop). I guess you could say that the machine has a kind of "if" built in, but it is very simple: it can only jump forwards or backwards.

You might find it informative to study the [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) of a simple CPU such as the [Atmel AVR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR_instruction_set) to get an idea about what a CPU can natively do.

> And how did the early programmer's know what to type, using only binary?

I guess they had a big list of all the instructions that the processor knew how to interpret. Or maybe an [instruction set manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0856.pdf).

By the way, early programmers didn't type, they entered code on [punch cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card), or by flipping banks of switches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those links, they are really helpful! Was the language you wrote in assembly?

Comment: @AntonD no problems. The language I wrote in was a kind of made up assembly. There will usually be some kind of TEST, JNZ, STORE, and JUMP instructions. They might be named differently though. And I used the variables a and b, which you can sometimes do but this is cheating: not all assemblers (or CPUs) make dealing with variables so easy. I did that to simplify the explanation.

Comment: Computers which ran electronically-stored programs were pretty advanced.  Computers before that were often programmed using wires.  A that could run a 32-step program using 8 registers and had 8 operations it could perform might have four attachment points for each allowable program step, three points for each register (fetch op1, fetch op2, and store), and a socket for each allowable operation.  If step 3 was supposed to add register 3 to register 5 and store the result to register 6, wires would connect the "step 3" attachment points to "register 3 fetch1", "register 5 fetch2", ...

Comment: ..."operation ADD", and "register 6 store".  One would "save" a program either by hand-copying a diagram of the wiring, or taking a photograph of it, and "load" a program by stringing the appropriate wires again.

Comment: @supercat: are you talking ablut  [plugboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plugboard)?

Comment: I always liked the idea of [rope memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_rope_memory) myself: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P12r8DKHsak